# Probability of a random Permutation

Tags: probability, statistics

Pick up a random permutation in S5(assuming all elements have the equal chance to be picked). Find the probability that the sum of the first three entries of σ is less than or equal to sum of last two.

My try: I mean there will be 5! different combination possible, do I have to look at each of it?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the permutations you want are just :
$ (...,5,4)$, $(...,5,3)$, $(...,4,5)$, $(...,3,5)$, $(...,2,5)$ and $(...,2,5)$ and you don't care about the order of the other elements where I put the dots.
So the probability is:
$$\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: Won't we include (...,5,2) and (...,2,5) as it asks for less than or equal to?

Comment: So, there will be six cases like this ( 4 you have mentioned and 2 by me).
And the probability should be (6* 3!)/120?
Because we can arrange the first three elements in 3! ways.

Comment: You are right!! :D

Comment: 4+2+1 =7 ? How come is this 8?

Comment: sorry! I'm super tired (and slightly drunk).

Comment: No problem!!! Thank you so much :)